# Terraform cloud stuck after AWS session timeout

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws, terraform-cloud

on https://app.terraform.io, I am on a workspace using AWS SSO credentials, meaning I have `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID` + `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY` + `AWS_SESSION_TOKEN` in my variables. My session can expire.

My problem is my AWS session did expire but the state is still in "PLANNING".

I tried "Cancel" and "Force canceled" but to no avail.

**It has been 5 days now and I would like to free my resources.**
I can do it manually but I wanted to keep my state in sync.

Note that this bug also exists on CLI, terraform just don't handle the session expired. But I least, I can interrupt it.

[image: terraform cloud]

*I created ticket #20704 on https://support.hashicorp.com/.*

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's more of a support request as the OP even mentions.

Answer (score 1):

The terraform team fixed it!

Now I have the expected behaviour of falling into timeout.

This is still not what it should do but it is enough for me => Behaviour identical to CLI.

```
Terraform v0.12.12
Configuring remote state backend...
Initializing Terraform configuration...
2019/11/13 23:04:09 [DEBUG] Using modified User-Agent: Terraform/0.12.12 TFC/6831c613a9
Refreshing Terraform state in-memory prior to plan...
The refreshed state will be used to calculate this plan, but will not be
persisted to local or remote state storage.


------------ Terraform Enterprise System Message ------------

WARNING: This plan has timed out and will now terminate!

Terraform Enterprise enforces a 30m0s maximum run time for this operation. Please
review the logs above to determine why the run has exceeded its timeout. You
can re-run this operation by queueing a new plan in Terraform Enterprise.

-------------------------------------------------------------

Error: wait: remote command exited without exit status or exit signal
```